# VSCode How to make Terminal RUN THE CODE IN MY PROGRAM

Tags: visual-studio-code

A few days ago, when I typed the above command in the Terminal

[image]

the Terminal should print out the statement: "Print this test statement"

Now for some reason, when I type that exact same command, it is now giving me the following result:

[image]

I tried this with multiple py files and it seems that when I type in the file name into the Terminal, what VSCode does is **OPEN/REOPEN** the file in the Editor, **not run the code** (print the test statement) in the Terminal like it did before.

By the way, it's not an apostrophe fault, tried that. This is really frustrating as a few days ago, when I typed in 'hello.py' into the terminal, it would print out the test statement. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you want to point something to a user who posted an answer then the appropriate place is the comments section as you have already done but you should not do it in your question. Also I recommend you read [ask] and pass the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the python prefix like this:

```
python hello.py
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It gives me this error now: https://imgur.com/a/tDmIuuY

Comment: Ok it seems you havent configured yet the env variables. can you show me the output of the command: path (i am asuming you have windows, correct me if otherwise)

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 by the way

Comment: This is after typing hello.py in the Terminal and pressing Enter/Return.

Comment: Could you suggest me some free Python IDEs that are similar to VsCode?

Comment: I mean type: "path". You have to add to the enviroment variable "path" the directory were python is installed. Sometimes, depending on the installing method, this last step is avoided. If you se my output [link](https://imgur.com/a/mgiG2w5) there is a path on C: were i installed python.

[link](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) See this how to.

Comment: If a solution can't be found for my problem in VSCode, I'll just use another Python IDE

Comment: Is not a problem of VS, is about the installation process of python. Dont worry this was something that happened to me a lot on Pycharm and any other ide. I still think VS is the best one for everything.

Comment: Follow this instructions: [instructions](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) Then restart VS

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. But I have to now type 'python hello.py' instead of just 'hello.py'. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions:
https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/. Then restart Visual Code

It should work now. But now, you'll have to type:

```
python program.py
```

instead of just:

```
program.py
```

in the Terminal.